# Android - How to show device unlock screen?

Tags: android, lockscreen, android-fingerprint-api, android-authenticator, android-biometric

[image]

How to show lock screen with device lock options. Here I have enrolled Pattern and Finger for unlocking device. So that Google pay showing above screen on launch.

How Do I show same device lock screen?